# sshfs You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of mounted directory

Tags: root, sshfs

Hello I am pretty new to using sshfs and I can view my mounted directory when I use root under the terminal. I do this by using

> sudo -i

Then I can navigate to my mounted directory and view my files, I want to be able to see them from the file system GUI and access them without being root. When I go to my file explorer I don't see my directory as a mounted directory, It simply looks like a binary file but it is not.

I think this would work if I was root throughout the system without having to use sudo -i in the terminal. If anyone has any insight to this it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Don't be root, and don't use `sudo -i` when using SSH or `sshfs`. Start with `sudo usermod -aG fuse username`, where `username` is your username. Log out and log back in, and try `sshfs` without `sudo`.

Comment: You should mark this as your answer. But I can't because it is a comment, so if you want to change it to answer because it did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be root, and don't use `sudo -i` when using SSH or sshfs.

It may be that you're not in the `fuse` group, and so you don't have the permissions to use FUSE mounting. Do `sudo usermod -aG fuse username`, where `username` is your username, to add yourself into the group. Then, log out and log back in, and use SSH and/or sshfs under your user account.